# State the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra for polynomials with real coefficients

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am working through a set of problems given to me and I have the following two questions presented to me:

1. State the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra for polynomials with complex coefficients.
2. State and prove the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra for polynomials
   with real coefficients from the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra for
   polynomials with complex coefficients.

I started to search the internet for both statements and when I search the second statement, I get in return the same result as the search for the first statement.

The search has provided me with this $\dots$
The fundamental theorem of algebra states that every non-constant single-variable polynomial with complex coefficients has at least one complex root. This includes polynomials with real coefficients, since every real number is a complex number with zero imaginary part.

So what is the different between both of these statements?

Comment: The tag is not the right one, even if there are proofs of (1) using complex analysis. But there are also proofs of (1) using only mean value theorem for odd degree real polynomials. I am amazed of the absence of an "algebra" tag, as this isn't that much commutative algebra. Sadly, I'm on mobile for a couple of days, so that I can't create new tags for now

Comment: @RobertGreen algebra was banned. Try abstract-algebra.

Comment: @MattSamuel It is funny, but I was on mobile that day, and the official mobile stackexchange app was not proposing abstract-algebra tag to... Odd...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- (1) means that each non constant polynomial with complex coefficients factors as product of degree $1$ (complex) polynomials
- (2) means that each non constant polynomial with real coefficients factors as product of polynomials of degree $1$ or of degree $2$ with strictly negative discriminant.
- (1) implies (2) because it shows *a fortiori* that any non-constant real polynomial has a complex root $z$, and by conjugation (as the polynomial has real coefficients), the conjugate $\overline{z}$ of $z$ is also a root. So complex and not real roots $z$ go by pair with conjugation, forming a degree $2$ polynomial $(X-z)(X-\overline{z}) = X^2 - 2\mathfrak{Re}(z) + |z|^2$ with discriminant $\delta = 4 \mathfrak{Re}(z)^2 - 4 |z|^2 = 4 \mathfrak{Re}(z)^2 - 4 \left( \mathfrak{Re}(z)^2 + \mathfrak{Im}(z)^2 \right) = - 4 \mathfrak{Im}(z)^2 < 0$ because $z$ is not real, leaving only real roots, and showing (2). This also shows that the irreducible polynomials with real coefficients are polynomials of degree $1$ and polynomial of degree $2$ with strictly negative discriminant.